# Windows 7 freezes at startup in safe mode with networking, and works in safe mode

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, freeze, safe-mode

I am working with Windows 7 on a laptop. Recently, my laptop froze during my session (and showed me quickly a blue screen). After that, it freezes always at startup, about 10 seconds after the Windows loading screen. It happens in *normal mode* and in *safe mode with networking*, but the *safe mode* works perfectly (no freeze).

`chkdsk C: /F /R /B` repaired some errors, but it didn't change anything about my problem.

I suspect a problem with my network card or its driver, but :

1. I don't know how to check it *in safe mode* ;
2. if it is true, I want to repair my laptop such that it can start in normal mode (even without networking) ;
3. if it is false, what are the other possible answers ?

Any idea about it ?

Answer (score 0):

After some research on the internet, I found a classic solution in such case : disable one by one all drivers that you suspect to cause the problem.

In safe mode, I disabled the two drivers associated with my network card (Ethernet driver and wi-fi adapter driver). Then, my computer started correctly in safe mode with networking. I enabled the wi-fi adapter driver : luckily, it worked (and gave me internet connection). It was up-to-date. Then the Ethernet driver, which wasn't up-to-date. I think that the Ethernet driver was corrupted. I don't know how...